# How to inject a value from GitHub workflow into Terraform?

Tags: github, terraform, github-actions, cicd

I have wrote a GitHub action workflow which creates a new repository using a hardcoded repository name. But now when I want to enhance it by asking the developer for a repository name [image: user input]

I'm having a hard time to inject the value from GitHub into Terraform. The working part of it is the pipeline does get the value inputed by the developer.
this is how it's configured
[image]
[image]

On the terraform side I have the name as environment variable
[image]

That is the error i'm getting
[image]

Document used to create that workflow:

- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions
- https://github.com/marketplace/actions/hashicorp-setup-terraform
- https://amazic.com/overriding-variables-in-terraform/

Answer (score 1):

In order to set env variable, sharable in the same job, you should redirect the oputput to the `$GITHUB_ENV` variable, as example:

```
echo "TF_VAR_INPUT_REPOSITORY_NAME=${{ github.event.inputs.repository-name }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

See more about Naming conventions for environment variables
[here in the doc](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#naming-conventions-for-environment-variables)

Comment: Thanks, I have redirected it using the command:
 "- run: echo TF_VAR_INPUT_REPOSITORY-NAME=${{ github.event.inputs.repository-name }} >> $GITHUB_ENV"
But still it doesn't able to read it on the Terraform side. 

TF file:
resource "github_repository" "test-repo" {
  name        = ${{env.TF_VAR_INPUT_REPOSITORY-NAME}} 

Error on Terraform Plan:
Error: Reference to undeclared resource
  on create_repo.tf line 2, in resource "github_repository" "test-repo":
   2:   name        = env.GITHUB_ENV
A managed resource "env" "GITHUB_ENV" has not been declared in the root
module.

Answer (score 0):

I did configured the run command to execute:
echo "TF_VAR_INPUT_REPOSITORY_NAME=${{ github.event.inputs.repository-name }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

[image: how to declare it in the root module of terraform]

Comment: I would assume that you should use a variable.tf declaration and use var.input_repository_name which is set to the value of TF_VAR_INPUT_REPOSITORY_NAME by default AFAIR